# Moving from 12.x IOS to 15.x IOS - Cisco 3750G

Tags: cisco-ios, cisco-ios-12, cisco-ios-15, cisco-3750

Is there any issue with jumping from IOS version 12.2(35)SE5 to 15.0.2-SE11 on a Cisco WS-C3750G-48PS-S switch?

Should I upgrade to the latest 12.x first (12.2.55-SE12), and then move to the 15.x based IOS, or can I hop straight to 15.x?

```
Switch   Ports  Model              SW Version              SW Image
------   -----  -----              ----------              ----------
*    1   52     WS-C3750G-48PS     12.2(35)SE5             C3750-IPBASE-M
```

Comment: You can jump directly to your desired version without issues. The switch will upgrade the motherboard and various controllers in the boot phase.

Comment: @user56700 You should convert your comment to an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting comment to an answer.

You can upgrade from version `12.2(35)SE5` directly to the newest IOS version for the switch 3750 series found on Cisco download center.

The upgrade process will automatically detect your system and upgrade various onboard controllers accordingly to support the new version. There's no need to do a midway upgrade.